# Spring RequestPostProcessor "with user" vs "with httpBasic" difference?

Tags: spring-security, basic-authentication

I am playing around with Spring Security.

I noticed something strange and this makes me wonder **what's the difference between**

```
org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.httpBasic;
and 
org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user;
```

**?**

what troubles me is this unit test:

```
@Test
public void testHelpUnauthorized() throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(get("/api/help")).andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    mvc.perform(get("/api/help").with(user("user").password("jj"))).andExpect(status().isOk());
    mvc.perform(get("/api/help").with(httpBasic("user",""))).andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    mvc.perform(get("/api/help").with(httpBasic("user","dd"))).andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
}

@Test
public void testHelp() throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(get("/api/help")
                    .with(httpBasic("correctUser","CorrectPassword"))).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

all this succeeds.

notice the second call, from the first test:

```
mvc.perform(get("/api/help").with(user("user").password("jj"))).andExpect(status().isOk());
```

why does this returns `200 OK`?
The only difference is how I pass the username-password pair.

More details:

1 - the REST endpoint returns just a string, made it so that I can test the authentication, no real functionality.

2 - All my users are defined, for the sake of just playing around with Spring Security in `new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);`  And when I test the behaviour through Postman/curl/browser, I get the correct behaviour, but not in the unit test, why?

Answer (score 2):

The difference can be found in the Javadoc of each method.

From the Javadoc of `httpBasic(String username, String password)`:

> Convenience mechanism for setting the Authorization header to use HTTP Basic with the given username and password.

This means if you perform a request with `httpBasic("user","password")`, then the credentials "user" and "password" are Base64 encoded and included in the request in the `Authorization` header.
The request then goes through the filter chain, which checks if the credentials are correct.

From the Javadoc of `user(String username)`:

> Establish a `SecurityContext` that has a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` for the `Authentication#getPrincipal()` and a `User` for the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken#getPrincipal()`. All details are declarative and do not require that the user actually exists.

The last sentence states that the user does not need to exist.
This means that if you perform a request with `user("user").password("password")`, a user with the username "user" and the password "password" is added to the `SecurityContext`.
This does not check if the user exists.
This is useful for testing your business logic, rather than testing the credentials.
For example if your logic requires you to retrieve the user's username. Another example is if you have different behaviour for different user roles (ADMIN / USER).